# jQuery Mobile CSS files confusion

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

After creating a new ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile application, under the folder Content there are some CSS files from jQuery and also the following two files:

- jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.css
- jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css

Now I'm wondering. The content of the two files are nearly the same. Also deleting the jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.css does not affect the appearence of the application.

What is the purpose of jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the two files it looks like jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css contains jQuery mobile themes as well as other jQuery mobile related styles and settings while jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.0.css contains only the themes themselves..

I would assume this is for either of two reasons..

1) either you want to use only the themes but not the jquery mobile styles
2) or you want to use the jquery.mobile.theme file to create custom themes

I am wondering though why new MVC application files start with that .theme file because if you look at the actualy jQuery website download section for jquery mobile - http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/#download - the .theme file isn't even part of the official downloads from there